# Advice about how to make Z3 evaluate simple constraints faster

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, constraints, z3

I'm trying to use Z3 (with C++ API) to check if lots of variable configurations satisfy my constraints, but I'm having big performance issues.

I'm looking for advice about which logic or parameter setting I might be able to use to improve the runtime, or hints about how I could try and feed the problem to Z3 in a different way.

Short description of what I'm doing and how I'm doing it:

```
//_______________Pseudocode and example_______________

context ctx()
solver s(ctx)

// All my variables are finite domain, maybe some 20 values at most, but usually less. 
// They can only be ints, bools, or enums. 
// There are not that many variables, maybe 10 or 20 for now.
//
// Since I need to be able to solve constraints of the type (e == f), where
// e and f are two different enum variables, all my
// enum types are actually contained in only one enumeration_sort(), populated
// with all the different values.

sort enum_sort = {"green", "red", "yellow", "blue", "null"}

expr x = ctx.int_const("x")
expr y = ctx.int_const("y")
expr b = ctx.bool_const("b")
expr e = ctx.constant("e", enum_sort)
expr f = ctx.constant("f", enum_sort)

// now I assert the finite domains, for each variable
// enum_value(s) is a helper function, that returns the matching enum expression
//
// Let's say that these are the domains:
//
// int x is from {1, 3, 4, 7, 8}
// int y is from {1, 2, 3, 4}
// bool b is from {0, 1}
// enum e is from {"green", "red", "yellow"}
// enum f is from {"red", "blue", "null"}

s.add(x == 1 || x == 3 || x == 3 || x == 7 || x == 8)
s.add(y == 1 || y == 2 || y == 3 || y == 4)
s.add(b == 0 || b == 1)
s.add(e == enum_value("green") || e == enum_value("red") || enum_value("yellow"))
s.add(f == enum_value("red") || f == enum_value("blue") || enum_value("null"))

// now I add in my constraints. There are also about 10 or 20 of them, 
// and each one is pretty short

s.add(b => (x + y >= 5))
s.add((x > 1) => (e != f))
s.add((y == 4 && x == 1) || b)

// setup of the solver is now done. Here I start to query different combinations
// of values, and ask the solver if they are "sat" or "unsat"
// some values are left empty, because I don't care about them
expr_vector vec1 = {x == 1, y == 3, b == 1, e == "red"}
print(s.check(vec1))

expr_vector vec2 = {x == 4, e == "green", f == "null"}
print(s.check(vec2))

....

// I want to answer many such queries.
```

Of course, in my case this isn't hardcoded, but I read and parse the constraints, variables and their domains from files, then feed the info to Z3.

But it's slow.

Even for something like ten thousand queries, my program is already running over 10s. All of this is inside s.check(). Is it possible to make it run faster?

Hopefully it is, because what I'm asking of the solver doesn't look like it's overly difficult. 
No quantifiers, finite domain, no functions, everything is a whole number or an enum, domains are small, the values of the numbers are small, there's only simple arithmetic, constraints are short, etc.

If I try to use parameters for parallel processing, or set the logic to "QF_FD", the runtime doesn't change at all.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Update: bit-blasting ended up being way slower, even for a very small amount of bits (6/8/10). I think it's because every query essentially has a push/pop, which makes it impossible to use large number of the bultin optimizations / precomputation techniques? [br]

Replacing enumeration_sort() with int_sort(), by manually encoding the strings into ints, didn't help at all. The only thing that seemed to help was to assert range-inequalities, as Patrick proposed. (if domain of X is {1,3,4,5,8}, it's useful to also assert X >= 1 && X <= 8)

It turns out that I can't use Z3 for this after all.

Comment: Update: it's more fitting to use a more specialized CSP solver for this. I'm trying out Gecode, and it seems to be working faster.

Comment: I concur with the idea of using CSP solvers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Ideas:

- **1.** Replace `x == 1 || x == 3 || x == 3 || x == 7 || x == 8` with `(1 <= x && x <= 8) && (x <= 1 || (3 <= x) && (x <= 4 || 7 <= x)`. Similar change with `y`.

  **rationale:** the solver for linear arithmetic now knows that `x` is always confined in the interval `[1,8]`, this can be useful information for other linear equalities/inequalities; it may be useful to also learn the trivial mutual exclusion constraints `not(x <= 1) || not(3 <= x)` and `not(x <= 4) || not(7 <= x)`; there are now exactly `3` boolean assignments that cover your original `5` cases, this makes the reasoning of the linear arithmetic solver more cost-efficient because each invocation deals with a larger chunk of the search space. (Furthermore, it is more likely that clauses learned from conflicts are going to be useful with subsequent calls to the solver)

  (Your queries may also contain set of values rather than specific assignments of values; this may allow one to prune some unsatisfiable ranges of values with fewer queries)
- **2.** Just like @alias mentioned, Boolean variables ought to be Booleans and not 0/1 Integer variables. The example you provided is a bit confusing, `b` is declared as a bool const but then you state `b == 0 || b == 1`
- **3.** I am not familiar with the `enum_sort` of `z3`, meaning that I don't know how it is internally encoded and what solving techniques are applied to deal with it. Therefore, I am not sure whether the solver may try to generate trivially inconsistent truth-assignments in which `e == enum_value("green")` e `e == enum_value("red")` are both assigned to `true` at the same time. This might be worth a bit of investigation. For instance, another possibility could be to declare `e` and `f` as `Int` and give them an appropriate interval domain (as contiguous as possible) with the same approach shown in  **1.**, that will be interpreted by your software as a list of `enum` values. This should remove a number of Boolean assignments from the search space, make conflict clauses more effective and possibly speed-up the search.
- **4.** Given the small number of problem variables, values and constraints, I would suggest you to try to encode everything using just the Bit-Vector theory and nothing else (using small-but-big-enough domains). If you then configure the solver to encode Bit-Vectors *eagerly*, then everything is bit-blasted into SAT, and `z3` should only use Boolean Constraint Propagation for satisfiability, which is the cheapest technique.

---

This might be an X Y problem, why are you performing thousands of queries, what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to explore all possible combination of values? Are you trying to perform model counting?

Comment: Thank you SO much for taking the time to share these ideas. I'll try implement them, and will post here what had the best effect.

I think I'll be able to "bit-blast" it. 

As for the wider context,  I'm trying to write a generator for combinatorial testing (IPOG), but one that would only generate tests that satisfy a set of constraints. These testsets get huge, so there's a lot of checking to do.

About the bools, I think this is interpreted as (b || !b), and the solver just simplifies the assertion away. It is a messy way to write it, sure.

Comment: @LeonardInkret I just read the comments you added under your question. Instead of listing by hand the assignments that you want to check, did you by any chance try the other way around? **i.e.** Incrementally extract all the models of the formula using a blocking clause to remove each previously visited solution one by one. In this way there is no `push/pop` and the solver can explore the solutions in the order it makes it more sense to him [it may benefit from locality].

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but there are easily millions/billions of models that could be extracted, and I'm only interested in certain ones. 

I'm currently using the Gecode library, and it's working fast enough

Answer (score 2):

Is it always slow? Or does it get progressively slower as you query for more and more configurations using the same solver?

If it's the former, then your problem is just too hard and this is the price to pay. I don't see anything obviously wrong in what you've shown; though you should never use booleans as integers. (Just looking at your `b` variable in there. Stick to booleans as booleans, and integers as integers, and unless you really have to, don't mix the two together. See this answer for some further elaboration on this point: [Why is Z3 slow for tiny search space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978097/why-is-z3-slow-for-tiny-search-space/55996274#55996274))

If it's the latter, you might want to create a solver from scratch for each query to clean-up all the extra stuff the solver created. While additional lemmas always help, they could also hurt performance if the solver cannot make good use of them in subsequent queries. And if you follow this path, then you can simply "parallelize" the problem yourself in your C++ program; i.e., create many threads and call the solver separately for each problem, taking advantage of many-cores your computer no doubt has and OS-level multi-tasking.

Admittedly, this is very general advice and may not apply directly to your situation. But, without a particular "running" example that we can see and inspect, it's hard to be any more specific than this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The link was very informative. I'll try to edit the code to care about booleans more. (Currently, I have expressions like (b == 0) everywhere)